# Diagonal Textbox border styling by css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Can anybody help me styling a textbox border like in image only by css.I have tried the following css but not working perfectly

```
.addfolder-input {
    border: medium none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-top: 0;
   border-right: 0;
   border-bottom: solid 2px #3c5a9a;
   border-left: 0;
   border-radius:5px;
}
```

[image: Textbox Style]

Comment: Are you fine if container `div` is added around the text box? Achieving that border with just the text box element I don't think is possible and text boxes cannot have pseudo-elements attached to it.

Comment: i would not be having a problem with div around input @Harry

Comment: @Harry: thanks for the tag :).. ketan : thank u.but the below answer is what exactly is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible approach by using a container element around the text box and then adding an absolutely positioned pseudo-element to the container which is rotated along the X-axis with a bit of perspective.

Rotating along the X-axis with perspective makes the rectangle look as though it sides are going away from each other as we go from bottom of the rectangle to its top. The top-border of the pseudo-element is nullified as we don't need it.

Whatever `width` is required for the text-box should be set to the container as both the pseudo-element and the text-box derive their `width (100%) from their container.

```css
.addfolder-input {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 48%;
  left: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #3c5a9a;
  border-top: none;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(-10deg);
  transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="addfolder-input" value="Type Something..."/>
</div>
```

---

Here is another alternate using multiple backgrounds, linear-gradients and background positioning. This can also work but in some browsers the angular edges/borders become a bit jagged.

```css
.addfolder-input {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 85%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 6px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}
.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 48%;
  left: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 9%, #3c5a9a 9%, #3c5a9a 12%, transparent 12%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 9%, #3c5a9a 9%, #3c5a9a 12%, transparent 12%), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 9%, #3c5a9a 9%, #3c5a9a 95%, transparent 11%) no-repeat;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 9%, #3c5a9a 9%, #3c5a9a 12%, transparent 12%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 3%, #3c5a9a 3%, #3c5a9a 6%, transparent 6%), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 9%, #3c5a9a 9%, #3c5a9a 86%, transparent 86%) no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 9%, #3c5a9a 9%, #3c5a9a 12%, transparent 12%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 3%, #3c5a9a 3%, #3c5a9a 6%, transparent 6%), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 9%, #3c5a9a 9%, #3c5a9a 86%, transparent 86%) no-repeat;  
  background-position: 0px 6px, 107px 6px, 0px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="addfolder-input" value="Type Something..." />
</div>
```

Comment: @aashi: Always glad to be of help :)